# Having trouble with a geometry excercise which includes 2 varying angles

Tags: geometry, triangles

I'm having trouble with a geometry exercise which wants me calculate the angle y using the given angle a. 
The main Problem I have with the exercise is, that almost all non given and angles are varying, making it very difficult to calculate the solution.

I'm not sure if I'm missing a theorem, but I just don't see the way in which y and a are connected in a usefull way, especially considering that neither are circle chords. Can somebody help me out? Its excercise 32 btw, I'll probably just need a nudge in the rigth direction
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For better understanding take a look on the item 1 and 4 here: (https://mathbitsnotebook.com/Geometry/Circles/CRAngles.html)

By central angle theorem we have $arc(CD)=\alpha$.

Then,

$$\delta=\frac{arc(CD)+arc(AB)}{2}=\frac{\alpha+180º}{2}=90º+\frac{\alpha}{2}$$

Comment: Looking at this picture: https://mathbitsnotebook.com/Geometry/Circles/angleChord.jpg where are the angles that are 34 and 54 degrees respetivly? Looking at the picture, it seams they are BEC and AED, but reading the article,  it says they are AD CB, which doesn't really make sense, since those are lines and not angles. Could explain what is meant by mAB and mCD? Because I'm not familliar with that notation

Comment: $arc(CD)$ means the arch $CD$ on the circle measured in radians. In this case I'm not talking about the length of $CD$ on the circle. In fact, $arc(CD)$ is a angle. Take a look at the Central Angle Theorem, it says that $arc(CD)$ is equal to the angle $\alpha$ measured in radians. That is the issue that you have to know in order to solve that problem.

Comment: My Problem is understanding the theorem  4 mentioned in the article you linked.  It says if I get one of 4 angles I can calculate the other 3, I just don't udnerstand is which are these 4 angles they are talking about because I'm not familliar with the notation, I think I undestand your formula, I just don't get why with works.

Comment: I think you should talk about that with your teacher. That theorem (in the link) is a pretty basic stuff to solve problems like that. Once I don't know what you have learnt in your class this conversation can take a very long time. After talk to your teacher we can talk again.

Comment: Problem is I'm German so thats probably why I'm having trouble getting it through my head. I think I'll just see if I can find another article about the topic. Thanks for your time